# What does sed s/[a-z AZ 0-9 _]//g do?

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I see these lines in my study materials:

```
$temp = 'echo $line | sed s/[a-z AZ 0-9 _]//g'
IF($temp != '')
   echo "Line contains illegal characters"
```

I don't understand. Isn't sed like a substituting function? In the code, `[a-z AZ 0-9 _]` should be replaced with ''. I don't understand how this determines if `$line` has illegal characters.

Comment: If all the legal characters are removed (which is what the `sed` does) and the result is not empty then it means there were illegal characters left over.

Comment: What shell is that?

Comment: Echoing BenjaminW's comment, your code has multiple syntax errors for any shell I am familiar with. Try https://shellcheck.net/ to get some of them pointed out to you.

Answer (score 3):

`sed` is a stream editor tool that applies regular expressions to transform the input. The command

```
sed s/regex/replace/g
```

reads from stdin and every time it finds something matching `regex`, it replaces it with the contents of `replace`. In your case, the command

```
sed s/[a-z A-Z 0-9 _]//g
```

has `[a-z A-Z 0-9]` as its regular expression and the empty string as its replacement. (Did you forget a dash between the A and the Z?) This means that anything matching the indicated regular expression gets deleted. This regular expression means "any character that's either between `a` and `z`, between `A` and `Z`, between `0` and `9`, a space, or an underscore," so this command essentially deletes any alphanumeric characters, whitespaces, or underscores from the input and dumps what's left to stdout. Testing whether the output is empty then asks whether there were any characters in there that *weren't* alphanumeric, spaces, or numbers, which is how the code works.

I'd recommend adding `sed` to the list of tools you should get a basic familiarity with, since it's a fairly common one to see on the command-line.

Comment: So if its not an empty string, it has characters that wasn't deleted. And those wasn't deleted are characters that are not alphanumeric characters, whitespaces, or underscores. ohhhh I get it now thanks :)

Comment: As an aside, the multiple spaces in the character class are not wrong, but redundant. Repeating the same character multiple times does nothing; the notation basically defines a set of characters.